# Finding a closed-form of ${\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{n}}dt}}{x}-1}$ and its improper integral from $1$ to $\infty$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, improper-integrals, closed-form

First, I would like to give a disclaimer that I do not know whether or not a closed form actually exists.

Also, I am trying to find a closed form that fits all integer values for $x$.

I was messing around with Desmos and came up with this interesting function. My computer is too slow to run it properly so I had to get around that by plotting integer values for $x$ for all $0<x\le200$ as shown here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yzvgfh3qwb. Using Desmos, I was able to see that there could be an improper integral from $1$ to $\infty$.

Here is what I tried by hand:
$\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{n}}dt}}{x}-1=\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{n}}dt}-x}{x}=\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{n}}dt}-1\right)}{x}=\frac{1}{x}\cdot{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{n}}dt}-1\right)}$

I don't know how to simplify from here much less find the previously mentioned improper integral from here.

Comment: $$\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x}\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{n}}dt}}{x}-1=\frac{1}{x}\cdot{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t^{n}}dt}-1\right)}$$ Is **not** TRUE ?

Comment: Start by writing the integral in terms of the gamma function.

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^n}dt=\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{n})...$

Comment: It doesn't make sense to take the integral of a function that only takes in integer inputs. Even if you define $x$ as a real number to make $f(x)$ continuous on $[1,\infty)$, the summation operator $\sum$ typically deals with integers. Also, I don't think your computer is causing Desmos to run your Desmos inputs slowly. The program itself isn't optimized enough to handle that many calculations.